# Drupal 6 - "Link this field to node" not italicized for first list item

Tags: css, drupal, view, cck

Using CCK and a View, I have a block that displays 3 fields from my most recent content articles.  The first field is "Node:Title" and I have the box checked for 'Link this field to its node".  The block displays the correct content, and creates a link for the title field to the node, however the top item Title Node link is not italicized in the browser.  The remaining links are.  I can't figure it out.  Any suggestions.

If you'd like to see, its happening in the Recent News block at sunsetflipshow.com on the front page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the CSS. You have some unclosed `<i>` tags that are causing the issue. The first `<li>` is missing out on the party while the rest are being completely wrapped by a single `<i>` (and also contain their own nested ones).

Here's a screenshot of the rendered dom for the recent news list. If you still can't figure it out try posting your template code.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That was completely the right thing to look for.  I was using the Rewrite field option and I had a <I> before the post date and only a </> after it.  I changed the trailing tag to </I> and everything straightened out.  Huge thanks.